# Meteor's JavaScript throwing me an error

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using meteor for a quick site and I'm trying to make this div '#box' fit the viewport and then have the top cut off '#wrapping'. But all of these methods error or they fill the entire page instead of just the page size... So it'd be as tall as the viewport height is but you can scroll to the next page, (I'm doing a single page design) :)

```
    var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    $ '#box'.height() = $(Math.viewPortHeight - '#wrapping'.offset.top);
```

Comment: `$ '#box'.height()` , do you mean `$('#box').height()` ? Also `'#wrapping'.offset.top` -> `$('#wrapping').offset.top`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Oh sorry, forgot jquery methods used to other languages but now meteor's error report is as follows `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` for ln 2...

**EDIT** Fixed that, but now when I scroll down it still includes the div...

Comment: **EDIT** Fixed using css3's vh measurement :)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It's still broken sorry, I tried using css to fix it, but it won't allow me to remove a div's height...

Comment: Exactly what is broken? Are there JavaScript errors or is the page not how you want it to be. If there are no errors would you mind showing me whats working wrong, and how you expect it to work?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek for some reason this piece of code isn't making the #box 's height= the window size - the offset of the top...
`var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    var boxHeight = $('#box').height()
    boxHeight = $(Math.viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping').offset.top);`

Comment: Your assigning the height to a variable, not the element. Also is `Math.viewPortHeight` defined? I don't think that's a property of the `Math` object; do you mean just `viewPortHeight`? If there are error messages what are they?

Comment: i@SpencerWieczorek There is an error when I assign it to the element... **Error Code** `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`
My code is `var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#box').height() = $(viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping').offset.top);`

Comment: This is because: `$('#box').height() = ...` is not a proper assignment in jQuery, giving you the error message. I explained how to do it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as I pointed out in my comment. There are some syntax errors in your code here:

```
$ '#box'.height() = $(Math.viewPortHeight - '#wrapping'.offset.top);
```

We need parentheses around `'#box'` and `'#wrapping'`, and you will want to user `viewPortHeight` other than `Math.viewPortHeight` (since there is no such property in the `Math` object):

```
$('#box').height() = $(viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping').offset.top);
```

There are still a few problems here. In jQuery when you assign a property like `height` you do it like so `.height(newValue)` and to get the height you do this `.height()`:

```
$(...).height(newValue); // Sets the height to 'newValue'
$(...).height();         // Returns the height
```

What your doing in the code is this: `$(...).height() = ... ;` is not assignment, which is why you have your error. So you want to do it like in the example above:

```
var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
$('#box').height( viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping').offset().top );
```

[**Here is an example with multiple pages**](http://jsfiddle.net/ew9np3vu/2/)

Comment: I have tried this and when I entered this: `$('#box').height(viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping').offset.top);` in the console (chrome) it said: `ReferenceError: viewPortHeight is not defined`, also it is not resizing the box height at at all...

Comment: Don't you have it defined on line 1 of your code? `var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();`

Comment: Yes, I realised you have to put the variable in the console as well, but it's still not resizing the height of the box... Here's what I've got so far...
`$('#box').height(viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping'.height()).offset.top);`
Which throws no errors, but just isn't  resizing the box...

Comment: so like this: `var viewPortHeight = $(window).height();
    console.log(viewPortHeight);
    $('#box').height(viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping'.offset().top));` It still stays the same height...

Comment: No, like in my code above: `$('#box').height( viewPortHeight - $('#wrapping').offset().top );`. Your not closing `#wrapping` properly.

Comment: Ah thanks, now it's kinda working, however now it let's me scroll... So all it's done is move it down, anyway to get rid of that?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you mean, maybe making a jsfiddle? I assumed you wanted something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ew9np3vu/2/

Comment: The colored area seems to be the same size as the screen. Is that not what you want?

Comment: That's what jsfiddle seems to be doing, but on my site it lets you scroll down...

Comment: Well what you said in the question: "tall as the viewport height is but you can scroll to the next page", means it's taller than the page. Because there are probably other elements. I assumed by scroll would be scrolling down goes to the next pages, what did you mean when you said scroll?